# Usar :before para añadir un contenido SVG a un div

Tags: html5, css3, svg

Es posible usar `:before` de `CSS` para agregar un contenido SVG a un elemento `div`, por ejemplo:

```
#midiv:before {
   content: "<svg>...</svg>"
}
```

En este ejemplo el contenido agregado al `<div>` podría ser cualquier figura generado mediante la correspondiente etiqueta `<svg>`, lo he intentado pero me muestra el contenido como texto no la figura respectiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad si que puede utilizar un `svg` dentro del atributo `content` de un elemento `:before`. Sin embargo, no lo podrás añadir directamente y tendrá que ser a través de una `url`.

Te dejo dos formas:

### Añadiendo el svg como fichero externo

Puedes importar el `svg` con una url dentro de tu atributo `content`.

```
#midiv:before {
   content: url("fichero.svg");
}
```

donde `fichero.svg` sería el fichero en el que tuvieras contenido tu `svg`.

### Añadiendo el svg como una URI

En el caso de que no quisieras utilizar un fichero externo, puedes añadir tu svg como una data URI. Esto te permitirá tratar tu `svg` como si fuera una url.

Ejemplo:

```css
#midiv{
   background-color: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

#midiv:before{
   content: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='100' width='100'><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' fill='red' /></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div id="midiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La misma pregunta se hizo en inglés y hasta donde encontré **no** es posible ya que el contenido se toma como STRING puro y el etiquetado de HTML no tiene efecto.

Te dejo el enlace correspondiente:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text

Answer (score 1):

No es posible, ya que trata la cadena como un *literal* y no como *lenguaje de marcado de hipertexto*.

**Ejemplo:**

```css
#midiv:before {
   content: "<svg>Esto no es posible, ya que trata a content como un literal</svg>";
}
```

```html
<div id="midiv"></div>
```

Como se puede observar en el ejemplo, la etiqueta `<svg>` escrita en *content* es tratado literalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría JQuery... y usas la función .before() de tal manera que quedaría algo así...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Before in JQuery</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Encabezado</h1>
<p>Parrafo</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("h1").before("<img style='width:50px;' src='https://weboverhauls.github.io/demos/svg/checkmark.svg'>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

y funcionaria perfectamente para lo que quieres...